# GUI by hand coding

Tags: java, swing

I have a jframe that would like to be like this:
[image]

Here is my code, But show a full screen button!

```
public class editFrame extends JFrame {

JButton saveButton;
JButton cancelButton;

public editFrame() {
    Component add = this.add(createForm());
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(100, 50, 500, 600);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public JPanel createForm() {
    String[] labels = {"ID", "Name", "Date", "Borrow Status"};
    // Create and populate jpanel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(labels[i], JLabel.TRAILING);
        panel.add(l);
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        l.setLabelFor(textField);
        panel.add(textField);
    }
    SpringLayout sL = new SpringLayout();
    panel.setLayout(sL);
    SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel, 4, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6);
    
    return panel;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            editFrame edF = new editFrame();
        }
    });
}
}
```

I am trying using spring layout , But now is:
[image]

All jtextfields are so big!!

Comment: `Can i use Spring Layout for this?` You are not limited to a single layout manager. You can create multiple panels where each panel has a different layout.

Comment: @camickr I update my code, But now my jtextfield are so big...

Comment: I added an answer to address the above question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All jtextfields are so big!!

Thats because a SpringLayout will size the fields based on the available space.

If you don't want them to grow in height that you can do:

```
//Component add = this.add(createForm());
Component add = this.add(createForm(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Or if you don't want them to grow in width or height you can wrap the panel in a panel that is using the FlowLayout since this will respect the preferred size of the component:

```
//Component add = this.add(createForm());
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add( createForm() ) ;
add( wrapper );
```

Comment: Your first statement has error when run...

Answer (score 6):

Check out the layout manager tutorials and the API. There you'll see that the JFrame's contentPane uses BorderLayout by default. When you add a component to a BorderLayout using container without specifying a layout constant, it gets added BorderLayout.CENTER, taking up the whole space and covering anything that was added previously.  The solution is to check out the layout manager tutorials, and then to start playing with the various layouts. Note that you'll often nest JPanels, each using its own layout to achieve complex GUI's in a simple way.

Comment: @Sajjad: regarding, `"Can you show correct code?"` -- Ah, why spoil your fun of playing with the layout managers and experimenting with your code? You'll learn much more from this exercise than for us to spoon feed you code. But please come on back and show your code if after attempts it's still not to your liking.

Comment: Which layout manager should i use?

Comment: That entirely depends on your needs and what you want your GUI to look like. I'd recommend the grid layout for your particular case.

Comment: @Sajjad- For my money, GridBagLayout will accomplish what you want from the screen shot, but it is one of the more complex layout managers. Check out [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for ideas

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can i use Spring Layout for this?

Comment: @Sajjad- Sure, I have no experience with it

Answer (score 0):

Definitely - use GUI builders for doing GUI. You will spend less time which you can invest in developing algoritms. For Eclipse there is [WindowBuilder Pro](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) and NetBeanIDE has GUI builder included.

Comment: And you will not understand layouts or the rudiments of the Swing library. I strongly argue against this route, especially when learning Swing. After you understand it, sure, go ahead and use these if desired, but doing so before this will hinder your gaining an understanding of the library.